# Firefox bug with position absolute inside table-cell

Tags: html, css, firefox

It looks like Firefox has a bug with `positon: absolute` inside of a table-cell displayed parent. Is there any way to fix this?

[Show case](http://jsfiddle.net/4bspR/7/)

It works well in Safari / Chrome but doesnt NOT work properly in Firefox (the browser treats `#css-table` as the parent instead of the `#css-table col`).

I wonder if there's a method to fix this without using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203225

It was logged over 10 years ago.

As a workaround you could use a div within the TD and set that to position:relative instead of setting it on the TD directly.